# Show Description only on certain collections

Tags: html, shopify

Have a Shopify website. All straightforward, only issue is I am trying to show collection descriptions only on certain collections.

If I enable collection title/description it shows up on all collection pages, just want it enabled on certain ones

Answer (score 0):

You can have different templates for collections.
You aren't saying what theme you're using, but most probably you already have different templates for collection.

In the collection page on the right, the last option is to set the template for that page.

You can modify the template in the Theme page.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even think about this!